# instaling c library in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu

I wanted to install libantlr3c-3.4 on ubuntu 12.04. In order to install it I followed the following steps:

The procedure which I am following now is:

```
1. tar -xzvf libantlr3c-3.4.tar.gz
2. ./configure
3. sudo apt-get install libc6-dev  
4. make 
5. make install
```

After this I got the following message:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during executiyon
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

After installing the library I tried to include the library in my netbeans project by setting the option

After this I include the header file as shown in the post: http://antlr.1301665.n2.nabble.com/SOLVED-ANTLR3-C-runtime-in-HP-UX-td3806962.html

But after doing everything I still end up getting the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:57,
                 from src/antlr3debughandlers.c:37:
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:383:24: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [antlr3debughandlers.lo] Error 1
```

Can someone please help me as to how should I get rid of this error

Comment: Most probably, you have compiled a 32bit library on a 64bit platform...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Ok..but in which step should I correct it. I am really a novice at c/c++. Therefore I am not getting. Thanks for ur comment :)

Comment: I guess you need to remove `libc6-dev:i386` and install `libc6-dev`, without the final `:i386`.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Thanks for the help. But now when I run make to install antlr3c I am getting the error: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory. Can you please help as to how should I resolve it

Comment: You also need `linux-libc-dev`. When missing a file, use http://packages.ubuntu.com to locate which package provides it.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Ok..thanks a lot for the help. But my system shows linux-libc-dev is already installed and continues to give me the error. Any workaround?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo The actual error message it is giving is: In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:57,
                 from src/antlr3debughandlers.c:37:
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:383:24: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I have updated my question too